# How can i cut/use part of object as object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this lamp object. And i marked with a red circle the part i want to cut and make as a different object. Only the yellow part i want to make it object. So i can later use it in the game is object and also as item.

[image: Lamp]

This is the lamp inspector:

[image: Inspector]

Comment: Split the lamp in to two game objects then remove the piece when picked up.

Comment: Is this a lamp you've made or did you get it from the asset store(or somewhere else).

Comment: @CNuts i didn't make it.  got it from somewhere else from a tutorial in youtube and package i downloaded including the lamp.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain That's my question how do i split it ? And how do i make the second part as gameobject ?

Comment: Unity can't split objects or cut objects if the lamp you got wasn't in two pieces there's not much you can do about it in Unity. Unless you use some mesh cutting script.

Comment: There are plugins you can buy that will do what you want.

Comment: Import the lamp into your favourite 3D modelling software, split the mesh, then export it separately from the lamppost into something like an FBX.

Comment: Is the lamp one complete `GameObject` or does it have children attached to it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a prefab of the lamp object and export it as a unity package.
You can then import it in other project as Custom package.

Source : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-exportpackage.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of the model u have (obj, fbx etc) u need to go to 3d Modelling software like Blender or Max to modify the model. There u would be able to do any change to model u would like to including diving in too and maybe changing of shapes! Once done u can import them back into unity and have two different objects!

Answer (score 0):

Taking the model into max as suggested would be the right idea.  You'll likely take it in as an FBX.

Once you seperate the lamp from the post you may want to affect it's pivot.

For MAX look [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/3ds-max/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/3DSMax/files/GUID-6872F014-4785-43D9-A83B-C774507907B3-htm.html)

Be careful when exporting out the fbx again.  I have noted that it seems to be best to export the model back out in metres.  Automatic unit conversion may give unwanted results.